# Python input deviates to first if statement

Tags: python

When I input a choice, with a couple of 'if' statements after it, all the other 'if' statements except for the first one is ignored. 
For example:

```
print('1. dostuff')
print('2. stuff')
choice = input('What do you want to do? ')
if choice == '1' or 'dostuff':
    domorestuff()
if choice == '2' or 'stuff':
    stuff()
```

Whatever I input, it will always go to 'domorestuff()'.

Comment: Hint: `bool('dostuff')`

Answer (score 7):

It should be:

```
if choice in ('1', 'dostuff'):
```

Right now, Python is reading your code like this:

```
if (choice == '1') or 'dostuff':
```

This means that it will *always* return `True` because `"dostuff"` will always evaluate to `True` since it is a non-empty string.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> choice = None
>>> choice == '1' or 'dostuff'
'dostuff'
>>> bool(choice == '1' or 'dostuff')
True
>>>
```

The solution I gave however uses the [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#in) keyword to test if `choice` can be found in the tuple `('1', 'dostuff')`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common mistake. It *should* be something like:

```
if choice == '1' or choice == 'dostuff':
       domorestuff()
if choice == '2' or choice == 'stuff':
       stuff()
```

You need to reiterate the `choice ==`. As is, the condition is being seen as:

```
if (choice == '1') or ('dostuff'):
```

which will always be true, since `'dostuff'` is [truthy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).